# Tabbar Controller image tint color error ios 7.1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

i have developed an anpp. And set color of tint image attiribute from properties.  it was working clearly untill upgrade ios 7.1.2. And now its all default blue image tint color. Is there anybody knows why it happens.

[image: Before IOS 7.1.2]

[image: After IOS 7.1.2]

Comment: Do you mean the color of the tabbar?

Comment: i have updated question with images Rohan.

Comment: are you using the property tintColor to set this?

Comment: No. i set image tint property  from right side  of xcode ;)

Comment: Try setting the barTintColor property for the same

Comment: doesnt work! all background of tabbar changed.

Comment: aah you want the color of the the items to be set....... so simply use tintColor property instead of barTintColor which is used for the background color